# Loading a lot of remote images - memory problems

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiimageview, uiimage

first of all, I am not using ARC as I had even bigger problems with it and I need full control of my memory management.

Here is the situation: I need to load a lot of remote JPEG images from a server and display them in a scrollview. The top images in the scroll view get released once the user scrolls down a bit. That is working, the containing views are all released normally.
Problem is, that after loading the remote image, a lot of memory stays allocated and doesn't get released.
Here is my code to fetch the remote images(subclassing UIImageView):

```
- (void)downloadImage    {
    NSData *posterData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:self.url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:nil];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:posterData];
    [posterData release];
    self.image = img;
    [img release];
}
// that gets called from:
- (void)setImageFromURL:(NSURL *)_url{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(downloadAndLoadImage) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
```

When I inspect my code with Instruments, my UIImageView gets released as intended, but the following still stucks in my memory and spams it:
[image: Instruments]

Apparently CFData, Malloc 9.00 KB, NSConcreteData are all resulting from my downloadImage method.
What am I doing wrong? This is driving me crazy...how do you load a lot of remote images memory safe? 
I also tried NSURLConnection, but it was rather worse then better. :(

Image size varies from 6 to 25KB.

Many thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I ended up using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) which works great and is very easy to use.

Comment: how did you declare your "`image`" property?  also, how big are the images you are attempting to download?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Image size varies from 6 to 25KB. The `image` property is `UIImageView`'s normal image attribute - I subclassed UIImageView in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is image downloading on a background thread? If yes then where is `NSAutoreleasePool`? You have to add:

```
NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

// your downloading thread code here

[pool release];
```

Or for ARC:

@autoreleasepool {

```
    // your downloading thread code here
```

}

Also if image download happens on a background thread you cannot do `self.image = img;` you should call it on the main thread, because UI elements should be modified only from the main thread:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:img waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Actually [SDWebImage library](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) does everything for you, and has memcache and disk cache

Comment: I tried NSAutoreleasePool already and there was no change. But thanks for pointing out the issue with the main thread. I just checked out SDWebImageLibrary and it improved things a lot. Malloc 9.00KB almost disappeared, but CFData still consumes a lot of memory.

Comment: I would be willing to bet that you are not dropping refs to your custom subclass of UIImageView and that the holding on to the UIImage and the NSData as a result. But, there is not way to know based on the code you posted.